# How to configure client side caching in Lettuce 6 Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I am trying to use new Lettuce 6.0 `ClientSideCaching` feature. But I am not sure how to configure it. Basically it needs `StatefulRedisConnection` which I am not sure how to get it. This is my configuration so far.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {
    private final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Map<String, SiteConfiguration> localCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public RedisConfiguration(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisOperations<String, Record> redisOperations() {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Record> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Record.class);
        serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        var redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Recordn>();
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(serializer);
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    //----------------------------------------------------|
    // This is not getting resolved                       v
    CacheFrontend<String, Record> cacheFrontend(StatefulRedisConnection<String, Record> statefulRedisConnection) {
        // Even this is not working connectionFactory.getConnection().getNativeConnection();
        return ClientSideCaching.enable(CacheAccessor.forMap(localCache), statefulRedisConnection, TrackingArgs.Builder.enabled().noloop());
    }
}
```

So, wondering what is the best way to configure this. Also is there any way to link this Caffeine or something instead of ConcurrentHashMap so that client does not store too much data.

Comment: For now, this is not supported with Cluster mode, if you are not using cluster mode, you can use Lettuce client, it will support that.